# How to add value and key in treemap by a specific index

Tags: java

I have tried

```
       int index = new ArrayList<String>(treemap.values()).indexOf("something");
```

But i am not getting how to replace the value and key.

Any help will be great.

Comment: TreeMap is sorted by its default order on Keys. For String key its in ascending order of characters or Integer it's in ascending order of numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, TreeMap is a sorted key map type. Keys are sorted by Red-Black tree algorithm. So keys are a in sorted order.

If you are interested in order in which your elements were added use LinkedHashMap.

Your question's anwer are:

- remove entry under you key
- add key with new value

Ps:
updating key and value means deleting old key, not changing it.

Map specification:

- HashMap - simple key/value pairs, unsorted, can't find insert order
- LinekdHashMap - unsorted, but keeps insert order
- TreeMap - sorts keys, but can't find insert order

Comment: why we need to remove the key first? why I can't set it again on same key. It'll overwrite the previous one. Isn't it?

Comment: Is LinkedHashmap shorted map?

Comment: @user4274413 LinkedHashMap maintain the **insertion order** but still you can't get it via index.

Answer (score 0):

`TreeMaps` don't work that way. They're not an indexed collection (unlike `Lists`), so what you're trying to do just won't work.

You need to remove the old one, if the key changes, and reinsert the new key-value pair.

Comment: why we need to remove the key first? why I can't set it again on same key. It'll overwrite the previous one. Isn't it?

Comment: That's why I said "if the key changes", since you seem to think that you can work with indexes somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Not efficiently feasible:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : treemap.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().equals("something")) {
        entry.setValue("entirely different");
        //treemap.remove(entry.getKey());
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: can I use `treemap.remove` while iterating?

Comment: If you immediately break, skipping the iterations.